# cohomology algebra of unordered configuration space on Euclidean space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, loop-spaces, configuration-spaces

In *Homology of $C_{n+1}$-spaces, $n\geq 0$,* F.R. Cohen,  *Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 533,* page 210 (the preface part before contents):

*Line 2:* ... is used to compute the precise algebra structure of $H^*(F(\mathbb{R}^{n+1},p)/\Sigma_p;\mathbb{Z}_p)$;

Is there any theorem in later chapters stating the precise algebra structure? I get lost and have not found the theorem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is Theorem 5.2 on page 246. The preceding remarks explain the notation. The proof comes later (in Section 11).